# Difference between address using array_name V.s &array_name?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-address

so I was studying about arrays and pointer to an array and I found this code.
I was wondering why the last one's address is FE14, isn't it suppose to be the address of the first element plus the (size of data type ) which is 4, so I should be FE04 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    printf("%p\n",arr); //----> the output FE00
    printf("%p\n",arr+1); //----> the output FE04
    printf("%p\n",&arr); //----> the output FE00
    printf("%p\n",&arr+1); //----> the output FE14
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, cast the pointers to type `void *` prior to printing them using the `%p` format specifier. Also, `arr` and `&arr[0]` are the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

This is confusing because of the way C arrays can decay into pointer expressions.

With `arr` and `arr+1`, the data type of the pointer is `int`, which on your system is 4 bytes, hence why you see the 4 byte difference between `FE00` and `FE04`.

With `&arr` and `&arr+1`, the data type of the pointer is `int[5]`, which is 20 bytes, hence why you see the 20 byte difference between `FE00` and `FE14`

It's a difference of `0x14`, which is:

```
  1 * 16^1 + 4 * 16^0
= 1 * 16   + 4 * 1
= 16       + 4
= 20
```

If you change the size of your `int arr[5]` from being 5 ints long to say, 500, you'll see a bigger difference between `&arr` and `&arr+1`.

Comment: thanx for your answer , I didn't knw that &arr will be 20 bytes .

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%p\n", arr+1);
```

In this code, `arr` is an integer pointer, so `arr + 1` results in `arr + 1 * sizeof(int)`, which is 4.

```
printf("%p\n",&arr+1);
```

In this one, `&arr` is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`, so `&arr + 1` results in `&arr + 1 * sizeof(int[5])`, which is 20 (14 in hexadecimal)